# Error while installing HDInsight Emulator

Tags: hadoop, emulation, azure-hdinsight

![enter image description here][1]

Getting error while installing HDInsight Emulator in windows 7. It says Installation fails with Hortonworks Data Platform. I am using Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0.

Find the logs below

> Exec:   HDP: Removing local/remote start/stop scripts, cluster.properties, smoke test 
>   CAQuietExec:  s cirpts and the credentials file Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\hdp\start_
>   CAQuietExec:  local_hdp_services.cmd' because it
>   CAQuietExec:    does not exist.
>   CAQuietExec:   At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.1.3.0-winpkg\scripts\uninstall.p
>   CAQuietExec:  s
>   CAQuietExec:   1:209 char:16
>   CAQuietExec:   +     Remove-Item <<<<  "$ENV:HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT\start_local_hdp_service
>   CAQuietExec:  s
>   CAQuietExec:   .cmd"
>   CAQuietExec:       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\hdp\start_local_hdp_services
>   CAQuietExec:
>   CAQuietExec:      .cmd:String) , ItemNotFoundException
>   CAQuietExec:       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remov
>   CAQuietExec:
>   CAQuietExec:      eItemCommand
>   CAQuietExec:
>   CAQuietExec:   Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\hdp\start_remote_hdp_services.cmd' because 
>   CAQuietExec:  i
>   CAQuietExec:   t does not exist.
>   CAQuietExec:   At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.1.3.0-winpkg\scripts\uninstall.p
>   CAQuietExec:  s
>   CAQuietExec:   1:210 char:16
>   CAQuietExec:   +     Remove-Item <<<<  "$ENV:HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT\start_remote_hdp_servic
>   CAQuietExec:  e
>   CAQuietExec:   s.cmd"
>   CAQuietExec:       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\hdp\start_remote_hdp_service
>   CAQuietExec:
>   CAQuietExec:      s.cmd:String) , ItemNotFoundException
>   CAQuietExec:       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remov
>   CAQuietExec:
>   CAQuietExec:      eItemCommand
>   CAQuietExec:
>   CAQuietExec:   Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\hdp\stop_remote_hdp_services.cmd' because i
>   CAQuietExec:  t
>   CAQuietExec:    does not exist.
>   CAQuietExec:   At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.1.3.0-winpkg\scripts\uninstall.p
>   CAQuietExec:  s
>   CAQuietExec:   1:211 char:16
>   CAQuietExec:   +     Remove-Item <<<<  "$ENV:HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT\stop_remote_hdp_service
>   CAQuietExec:  s
>   CAQuietExec:   .cmd"
>   CAQuietExec:       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\hdp\stop_remote_hdp_services
>   CAQuietExec:

Comment: What kind of error? Give us more input.

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: could not attach.. as reputation is not enough

Comment: You could use the Hortonworks sandbox instead